# Problem with Dual boot Linux Mint in my win 8 laptop

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dual-boot

This is my first time experience with any Linux OS. I am trying to dual boot linux Mint to my Toshiba Satellite Win 8.1 laptop(64 bit). I searched google on how to dual boot linux mint and below are the steps I have done so far:

1. Created a manual partition in my Win 8 laptop.
2. Downloaded linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit iso file via torrent. I have burnt the iso file to my USB memory stick using unetbootin tool(unetbootin-windows-608).
3. As suggested I have disabled secure boot and my Boot mode is set as UEFI by default.

Now when I reboot I do get the below 2 options:

1. Start Linux Mint
2. Start Linux Mint with compatibility mode

Either option I choose gives me a blank screen and nothing much. I am not sure what is the issue and how to proceed further.

Comment: My advice (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)) and leave out the chit-chat like "Thanks" and your name (a second time) from posts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine the cause of the problem. It could be that you chose incorrect partition during installation **and/or** the installer was not downloaded completely or something else.

I suggest you use `Windows-recovery-DVD` or something like that to recover your Windows as well as recovering the initial partition. As for installation of `linux-mint`, you better verify installer you downloaded from torrent using `md5sum` and organize the partition in `linux-mint` installation directly to avoid confusion.

Alternatively, you can also use gparted which can be installed to flash drive to manage your partition, but **please be careful** not to delete or modify (shrink or extend) partition that you are not sure about because this program is designed to do that in simple manner using GUI.

---

What you said is identical to what describes in tutorial for linux mint installation. I have no experience in Win 8, but I surfed a little bit and I found out that this EFI/UEFI is designed mainly for Win and one of the purpose is to avoid booting using other OSes as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot_2). But it seems there is a way to force EFI (or UEFI) to allow linux to installed there instead of CSM as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246409/dual-booting-in-csm-mode).

Comment: I checked the md5sum and it does matches with the downloaded file.  I reformatted my USB stick and installed the boot files again.  On reboot i get the grub menu with 2 options:  
 

1. Start Linux Mint  

2. Start Linux Mint with Compatibility mode

Either option I select gives me a blank screen.When I change the Boot Mode from UEFI mode to CSM Mode and selecting any of the options from grub menu gives me Linux Mint home screen

Comment: Ah, I had no idea it was the boot mode. You better put it as an answer in case anyone else get the same problem.

Comment: But the problem is every other time i need to log into Windows i get an error and i need to change the Boot Mode to UEFI. Does that means Linux Mint is not supported my my Laptop in UEFI mode ?

Comment: What you said is identical to what describe in this [tutorial] (http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1556) for linux mint installation. I have no experience in Win 8, but I browse a little bit and I found out that this EFI/UEFI is designed mainly for Win and one of the purpose is to avoid booting using other OSes as described [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/).  But it seems there is a way to force EFI (or UEFI) to allow linux installed there instead of CSM as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246409/dual-booting-in-csm-mode).